# React native crashes after changing compileSdkVersion to 31

Tags: android, react-native

after changing my compileSdkVersion from 30 to 31 my react native app crashes with error

[image]

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    // buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    // ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    fitnessVersion = "20.0.0"
    supportLibVersion = "30.0.0"
    kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
}
```

```
"react-native": "0.64.2",
"react": "17.0.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to update react native from version **0.64.2** to **0.68.4** which **compileSdkVersion** value is 31 by default in 0.68.4

Helpful [link](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.2&to=0.68.4) to upgrade you RN version